# Add class to a Dynamic Row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a script to add a row to my form table which is working absoulty fine. On my first input box I am using a datepicker which is working on the first row but when I add another row the datepicker isnet working. I'm assuming it's because there is no class. I have tried adding using this bit of code but with no luck: `newcell.className = 'datepicker';`

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 50){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            newcell.className = 'datepicker';
        }
    }else{
         alert("Too many rows.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to actually create the first date picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually [create the datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) on the element, at the end of the for-loop body. Also, don't copy the `innerHTML` of the original row, as will also copy the `id` of the input, which must be unique and will break the date picker logic.

A complete working example is below.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 50){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            
            newcell.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
          
            $(newcell).find('input').addClass('datepicker');
            $(newcell).find('input.datepicker').datepicker();
        }
    }else{
         alert("Too many rows.");

    }
}

$(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="addRow('table')">Add Row</button>

<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Javascript is not my strongpoint so could you please advise where my code needs to be changed.

Comment: The datepicker is within an input, i have attached the code below           <td>
       <input class="datepicker" type="text" required="required" name="date" data-date-picker="dd/mm/yyyy">
       </td>

Comment: @Jack See my updated answer for a complete, working example.

Comment: That is working well, thank you for going in to depth. If there was multiple input elements how would specify which element to apply the date picker too.

Comment: @Jack Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer (click the check mark under the voting buttons) if it helped. Creating multiple datepickers is just basic jQuery- any element or selector can be used: `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` or `$('input').datepicker();`. If you have new questions though, create a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).